# Error: "app" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm creating an `angular2` clientside app with a `node.js` server. clientside app seems to work perfectly fine, meaning that:

- All of my requests get proper responses.
- Application loads and works as expected.

but I get this error in terminal:

```
Error: The selector "app" did not match any elements
    at DomRenderer.selectRootElement (/home/mu-user/Projects/my-app/dist/server/index.js:27126:23)
    at selectOrCreateRenderHostElement (/home/mu-user/Projects/my-app/dist/server/index.js:15687:32)
    at AppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:12:16)
    at AppView.create (/home/mu-user/Projects/my-app/dist/server/index.js:50916:21)
    at ComponentFactory.create (/home/mu-user/Projects/my-app/dist/server/index.js:36656:36)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (/home/mu-user/Projects/my-app/dist/server/index.js:23313:40)
    at /home/mu-user/Projects/my-app/dist/server/index.js:23222:89
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.Call (/home/mu-user/Projects/my-app/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js:307:14)
    at Array.forEach (/home/mu-user/Projects/my-app/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js:1313:17)
```

which doesn't interrupt `webpack` or `http-server` .
The question is why I face this and how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you include some of your main files? Like index.html, bootstrap file, modules..

Comment: This is most likely some kind of ngModule related issue in that your app doesn't know about the main component. You need to show us some code we can help out

Comment: @echonax This project contains more than 50 components, it was almost impossible to add the whole code, but reverting to older commits to get a simpler version, I noticed that error is gone. so it couldn't be helpful either.

Comment: @JoshuaOhana I used an older commit to have a simpler version to show & I noticed it's working. that was the key to find out you were right. do you think this error is kind of "unhandled" or it actually intended to show  "app element not found"? caused I couldn't get the meaning unless you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this answer for record as I described in comments too. This bug has been solved by fixing references to modules included in declaration list of `ngModule`.
It was tricky to figure out the issue from the context of the error message. and also because of the code complexity it wasn't possible to include actual project code, but I figured out the issue while trying to make a simpler version ready to show here.